# Is there a way to rollback to a stock rom without "unlocked" icon on XT910?

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-razr

I'm looking forward to install new CM 10.1.3 to my Razr MAXX (XT910), but I see some bug reports about this version. I want to give it a try, but - is there a way to go back to the stock ROM if I don't like it? By "go back" I mean restoring it's original state, no "unlocked" icons.

Currently I have 982.124.14.XT910.Retail.en.FR (Android 4.1.2).

Comment: Please don't ask multiple question in one post, that makes it hard to answer. If you have multiple questions, ask them separately. That's how this site works, and this way it's also easier to keep track of them (and see what's answered and what not).

Comment: Modified. Now it's single question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock icon when you turn on your phone shows that the phone's bootloader is unlocked and doesn't show if it's rooted or not.

Just use the tool to you used to Root and unlock the bootloader to unroot and re-lock the bootloader it.

For info about the Razr XT910 have a look at this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1840296)

> By flashing a ROM or rooting your Razr voids Motorola Warranty Terms.
>   Even if you flash the same rom your Razr came with.  3. All the
>   devices are divided by regions. This means you can only flash a stock
>   ROM designated for your Razr region. Common Regions are: Latam (Latim
>   America 'n Canada) - Europe - Asia - PSHAsia - ME - China - Korea -
>   Japan(*

Comment: But, if I flash it back and no "unlocked" icon, how can they know it?

Comment: @relgames This device blows a [QFuse](http://blog.azimuthsecurity.com/2013/04/unlocking-motorola-bootloader.html) when you root the device, meaning [there is a permanent record of it being rooted](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/08/27/motorola-included-a-root-check-in-the-razr-razr-maxx-and-droid4-with-ice-cream-sandwich/), which can never be erased.